# Storing value in int array from mysql of type mediumint

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, realloc

I am new to C and working on a project at the moment but I am having an issue.

I have a int array which is defined as below:

```
int* SwitchIDs = malloc(sizeof(int));
int* SeizeUTC = malloc(sizeof(int));
int* CorrelationIDs = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

I run a query which retrieves values from the database, these values are something like below

```
 SwitchID | CorrelationID | SeizeUTC   |
+----------+---------------+------------+
|    14356 |      10355062 | 1305534091 |
|    14356 |      10366006 | 1305536411 |
|    14354 |      12283158 | 1305537718 |
```

In the database, the SwitchID is a `mediumint(8) unsigned`, the CorrelationID is of type `int(10) unsigned` and the SeizeUTC is of type `int(10) unsigned`.

This query that retrieves the results is executed several times so different values returned which need to be added to each of the arrays.

Once the query has executed I get the value of how many rows were returned and then I realloc each array as below and once realloc I then try adding the data from the database into each array as below. All of this is also done after checking that the result count > 0 Below is the code for the query and insert the data into the arrays.

```
sqlLen = asprintf(&sql, "SELECT SwitchID, CorrelationID, SeizeUTC FROM TblCallLog "
                "USE INDEX(indCalled) WHERE SeizeUTC BETWEEN %lu AND %lu AND CalledNumberID='%i'"
                "AND Direction = 1 %s",
                DateToUTC(reportParameterArray[P_DATESTART], *(int*)&reportParameterArray[P_TIMESTART]), 
                DateToUTC(reportParameterArray[P_DATEEND], *(int*)&reportParameterArray[P_TIMEEND]),
                NumberIDs[i], reportRestrictions->PResultContraint);

 if ((mysql_real_query(HandleDB, sql, sqlLen))) return 1;
        resultReport = mysql_store_result(HandleDB);
        resultCount = mysql_num_rows(resultReport);
        printf("***Result Count: %i***\n", resultCount);
        if (resultCount != 0)
        {
                SwitchIDs = realloc(SwitchIDs, resultCount*sizeof(int));
                CorrelationIDs = realloc(CorrelationIDs, resultCount*sizeof(int));
                SeizeUTC = realloc(SeizeUTC, resultCount*sizeof(int)); 

    while((rowReport = mysql_fetch_row(resultReport)))
            {
                SwitchIDs[insertCount] = atoi(rowReport[0]);
                CorrelationIDs[insertCount] = atoi(rowReport[1]);
                SeizeUTC[insertCount] = atoi(rowReport[2]);
                            printf("SwitchID[%i]: %i\n", insertCount, SwitchIDs[insertCount]);
                printf("CorrelationIDs[%i]: %i\n", insertCount, CorrelationIDs[insertCount]);
                printf("SeizeUTC[%i]: %i\n\n", insertCount, SeizeUTC[insertCount]);
                insertCount++;
            }
}
```

This seems to work for the first 5 inserts but then when it loops for the 6th time, it core dumps with a seg fault.

The stacktrace contains the following:

```
#0  0x400f24de in malloc_consolidate () from /lib/tls/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x400f24de in malloc_consolidate () from /lib/tls/libc.so.6
#1  0x00000038 in ?? ()
#2  0x401a88d8 in main_arena () from /lib/tls/libc.so.6
#3  0x080646c0 in ?? ()
#4  0x401a88c4 in main_arena () from /lib/tls/libc.so.6
#5  0x401a88a8 in main_arena () from /lib/tls/libc.so.6
#6  0x401a88a0 in __malloc_initialize_hook () from /lib/tls/libc.so.6
#7  0x401a7f0c in __elf_set___libc_thread_subfreeres_element___rpc_thread_destroy__ () from /lib/tls/libc.so.6
#8  0x401a88a0 in __malloc_initialize_hook () from /lib/tls/libc.so.6
#9  0xbfffeb04 in ?? ()
#10 0xbfffe474 in ?? ()
#11 0x400f4117 in _int_malloc () from /lib/tls/libc.so.6
Previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

I'm guessing this is because the mysql database is of type mediumint but I when I realloc I am saying sizeof(int) so its not big enough for the number and crashing.

I'm not sure how I can fix this as C doesn't have any concept of mediumint, at least, not as far as I am aware of or been able to find.

Comment: I can't see where you are incrementing `insertCount` in your `while` loop. Have I missed it? Also, could you add the code that does the query and the bit that sets `resultCount`, thanks

Comment: @Jimbo Sorry had a bit of a type, I've corrected the code

Comment: No probs. Could you add the code that does the query and the bit that sets resultCount, thanks

Comment: @Jimbo I've added the code for the query and where resultCount is set

Comment: `insertCount` initialised to zero?

Comment: @Jimbo, yea it is, its initialised at the top of the function using ``int insertCount = 0;`` as is resultCount also

Comment: Sorry Boardy, can't spot anything. I noticed in the mysql help page their example checks their equivalent of `rowReport[i]` for `NULL`. Is it possible one of these could be NULL in your table?

Comment: @Jimbo, I have just added a check to make sure its not null but not made any difference. Thanks for the help though

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32422/discussion-between-jimbo-and-boardy)